# algorithms animation

Tags: java, algorithm, swing

I am doing a little project I came across. The point is the be able to explain how the algorithms are working with animation for people with little or now knowledge about algorithms. I believe this is a project from the duke university. However I want to say that this is not homework, I am doing this only as an exercise. So the first image is what I am trying to do and the second image is what I have done so far. I am using Eclipse. So My question is how can i do an animation like the top part of the image with the green background. So if anyone can help please don't be shy. Here is the first image[image]

and this is my work.[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to override the `paintComponent(Graphics g)` method of the `JComponent`s you want to customize, you won't be able to do it with standard swing component (eg you can't animate a `JLabel` around).

In addition you can use a library that can help you drawing things like [Processing](http://processing.org/).

Comment: No, better to override `paintComponent(Graphics g)` not `paint(...)`, *especially* if he's doing animation. This way he'll have the benefit of automatic double buffering. I have edited your answer to reflect this.